# python reduce print statement line

Tags: python

how to reduce print statement line to below 80 characters. still want all to be printed on a single line in console

```
 print("Adding model: {0} with average giveaway of {1} created at {2}, which is {3} days ago"
                      .format(m.name,
                              m.tags["Mean Giveaway(g)"],
                              m.created_time,
                              (tmzUTC.localize(datetime.utcnow()) -
                               m.created_time).days
                              )
                      )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicit string concatenation:

```
print("Adding model: {0} with average "
      "giveaway of {1} created at {2}, "
      "which is {3} days ago"
      .format(m.name,
              m.tags["Mean Giveaway(g)"],
              m.created_time,
              (tmzUTC.localize(datetime.utcnow()) -
               m.created_time).days
              )
      )
```

Comment: so will the print statement be printed all on 1 line in console

Comment: Yes. String literals separated by whitespace are concatenated.